# WinForm Application Get value from dynamic textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, textbox

This has been a real struggle lately for me because this is what I need the most right now. I made 2 textboxes dynamic for a login form and want to get the values from the textboxes if I hit the login button. I have searched on the internet for possible values but none of them seem to work for me. The button and the textbox are made in a different class and that is the painful part for me. I cannot get the value from the textbox on the form to the event handler in the class where my buttons are made. If someone can help me with this one so I can go on with my project and be finish it off very soon.

I will leave some pieces of the code also for you. These pieces will be the class for the buttons and textboxes and the main form.

***Main Form***

```
            x_loc = 0;
            y_loc = 80;
            x_size = 100;
            y_size = 20;

            foreach(string item in lon.loginLbls())
            {
                clsLbl = new Labels(pnlMenu, x_loc, y_loc, x_size, y_size, item);
                y_loc += 50;
            }

            x_loc = 0;
            y_loc = 100;
            x_size = 200;
            y_size = 30;

            foreach(string item in lon.loginForm())
            {
                clsTxt = new Textboxes(pnlMenu, x_loc, y_loc, x_size, y_size, item);
                y_loc += 50;
            }


            x_loc = 0;
            y_loc = 200;
            x_size = 200;
            y_size = 30;
            foreach(string item in lon.loginBtns())
            {
                clsBtn = new Buttons(pnlMenu, x_loc, y_loc, x_size, y_size, item);
                y_loc += 50;
            }
```

***Button Class***

```
Button btn;



public Buttons(Panel parent, int x_loc, int y_loc, int x_size, int y_size, string name)
    {
        btn = new Button();
        btn.Location = new Point(x_loc, y_loc);
        btn.Size = new Size(x_size, y_size);
        btn.Text = name;
        btn.Name = name;
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnHandler);
        btn.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        btn.BackColor = Color.White;

        parent.Controls.Add(btn);
    }

    private void btnHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;

        switch (btn.Text)
        {
            case "Login":
                Login lgn = new Login();
                break;

            case "Afsluiten":
                Application.Exit();
                break;

        }
    }
```

***Textbox Class***

```
TextBox tb;

        public Textboxes(Panel parent, int x_loc, int y_loc, int x_size, int y_size, string name)
        {
            tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Location = new Point(x_loc, y_loc);
            tb.Size = new Size(x_size, y_size);
            tb.Name = name;
            tb.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            tb.BackColor = Color.White;

            parent.Controls.Add(tb);
        }
```

***Lists***

```
public List<string> loginBtns()
        {
            List<string> lgnBtns = new List<string>();
            lgnBtns.Add("Login");

            return lgnBtns;
        }

        public List<string> loginForm()
        {
            List<string> lgnForm = new List<string>();
            lgnForm.Add("username");
            lgnForm.Add("password");

            return lgnForm;
        }

        public List<string> loginLbls()
        {
            List<string> lgnLbl = new List<string>();
            lgnLbl.Add("Code");
            lgnLbl.Add("Wachtwoord");

            return lgnLbl;
        }
```

Note: All these methods are located in a different class.

Comment: You should really really avoid creating a class that acts as if was a class from the WinForms library

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit more in depth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ways to go:

1.Make creation on textboxes public:

```
partial class form1{
     TextBox tb = new TextBox();
...
}
```

then can get get its text whereever you like:

```
string a = tb.Text;
```

2.Get Textbox Controls of Parent:

```
TextBox[] tb = parent.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();
```

Now you have textboxes in an array. You may want to use the Tag to identify them:

```
  string a = tb.FirstOrDefault(t=>(string)t.Tag=="username").Text;
```

Of course in this case you must have set the `Tag` when adding the TextBox.

Comment: Thank you I will try this right now and see if I have any succes with this solution.

Comment: Question where to apply the second option? I tried to use it in the button class but I got the following error message: 'Queryable.OfType<TResult>(IQueryable)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context Kassa'

Comment: opps the code was missing parentheses. I just edited it. please have a look at it. `OfType<TextBox>` shoud be: `OfType<TextBox>()`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I will change and look what the result will be.

Comment: Okay the code is running right now but I am getting a NullRefferenceException when it gets into the: string a = tb.FirstOrDefault(t=>(string)t.Tag=="username").Text;

Comment: well clearly `FirstOrDefault` finds nothing (so the result is null) and this means that there is no tesxtboxes with tag **username**. I mentoined in the answer that if you want to use this method you must add the tag when creating textbox. of course the wourd `username` is an example you can use whatever you like